# Set the property value inherited from prototype, why the prototype value does not change?

Tags: javascript

I did some test in Chrome.
Quite simple, I change the inherited property value.
I assume the set would happen on prototype object, but the prototype value does not change.

Actually a new property is created on child object.
Is this expected?

```
> function Shape() {};
> var base = new function() { this.mValue = 10; };
> Shape.prototype = base;
> var s = new Shape();
> s.mValue = 20;
> base;

< Object {mValue: 10}
```

Comment: `s.mValue` is not from prototype. `mValue` is own property of object `s`

Comment: So the only way to change the prototype mValue is to get the reference of prototype first?  However the js does not allow you to get the reference of prototype from the object "s".

Comment: You should seriously reconsider why you want to change something in the prototype. There's very few situations where that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Set the property value inherited from prototype, why the prototype value does not change?

Because when you assign to `s.mValue`, it creates a *new* property on `s` which shadows the one on the prototype.

Property access works like this:

- If you're *getting* the value of the property, it first looks at the object itself to see if it has it. If so, it returns that object's value for it. If not, it looks to the object's prototype and returns the prototype's value if the prototype has it; if not, it goes to the prototype's prototype, and so on.
- If you're *setting* the value of the property, it sets it on the object itself, it doesn't go up the prototype chain.

Obviously that's the simple version. :-)

This can be a bit surprising if you're coming to it from class-based languages, but once you understand it, it's really simple.

Let's throw some ASCII-art at it for clarity. After this code:

```
function Shape() {};
var base = new function() { this.mValue = 10; };
Shape.prototype = base;
```

...we have something like this in memory:

```
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                  
Shape−−>|     function     |                  
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        | [[Prototype]]    |−−−−−> Function.prototype
        | prototype        |−+  
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                             +−−−>|    object     |                    
                             |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
base−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    | [[Prototype]] |−−−> Object.prototype
                                  | mValue: 10    |                    
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

*(If `prototype` vs. `[[Prototype]]` is unfamiliar to you, see the explanation at ¹ at the end of the answer.)*

Then we do:

```
var s = new Shape();
```

and get:

```
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                  
Shape−−>|     function     |                  
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        | [[Prototype]]    |−−−−−> Function.prototype
        | prototype        |−+  
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                             +−+−>|    object     |                    
                             | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
base−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | [[Prototype]] |−−−> Object.prototype
                               |  | mValue: 10    |                    
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
s−−−−−−>|      object      |   |        
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
        | [[Prototype]]    |−−−+
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

At this point, if we did `console.log(s.mValue)`, the JavaScript engine would look at `s` and, not finding a property with the name `mValue`, it would follow the `__proto__` link to get the prototype, and look there. Finding it there, it gets the value from there.

Then we do:

```
s.mValue = 20;
```

and get:

```
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                  
Shape−−>|     function     |                  
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        | [[Prototype]]    |−−−−−> Function.prototype
        | prototype        |−+  
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
                             +−+−>|    object     |                    
                             | |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
base−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |  | [[Prototype]] |−−−> Object.prototype
                               |  | mValue: 10    |                    
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                    
s−−−−−−>|      object      |   |        
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |
        | [[Prototype]]    |−−−+
        | mValue: 20       |
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

At this point, if we did `console.log(s.mValue)`, the JavaScript engine would look at `s`, find the property, and get its value from `s`.

---

Side note: `var base = new function() { this.mValue = 10; };` is a **really** long way to write `var base = { mValue: 10 }`. ;-) And it *very very very slightly* slows down access to the properties inherited from `Object.prototype`, as it inserts an extra unnecessary prototype in the chain. Also, you don't need to create a new object for `Shape` to assign to instances; it *already* has one.

So that code can be simplified to:

```
function Shape() {} // No need for ; after function declarations, they're not statements
Shape.prototype.mValue = 10;
var s = new Shape();
s.mValue = 20;
Shape.prototype;
```

(And as of this update to the answer in 2023, we probably wouldn't use `var`.)

Just FWIW.

---

¹ Re `prototype` and `[[Prototype]]`:

- `prototype` is a property some functions have that points to the object to assign as the prototype of an object created via `new` with the function. Example: `Date.prototype` points to the object that is used as the prototype of date instances created via `new Date`.
- `[[Prototype]]` is the internal field of objects that points to the object's prototype. Example: If you did `const d = new Date()`, `d'`s `[[Prototype]]` field points to `Date.prototype`. The `[[Prototype]]` field isn't accessible directly in code. You can access it by using `Object.getPrototypeOf(d)`, or (not recommended) by using the accessor property called `__proto__` defined in `Object.prototype`. (But don't use `__proto__` in new code. It's only for backward-compatibility with code written for a JavaScript engine that added that feature before standardization made it unnecessary, and note that objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype` don't have it.)

Comment: hello @T.J. Crowder +1 excellent, you mean that **any** operation (even a `delete object.property` ) only affects the **object itself**, the **prototype chain is never altered** (unless you explicitly alter it), right?

Comment: @Daniel - I'd hesitate to say something that broad. :-) Yes, `delete` only deletes the property if it's an own property of the target, it won't delete a property that's inherited. But you can certainly do things through an object that affect its prototype object, if the prototype object is written that way. For instance, an inherited method or property accessor might change the state of a prototype object (though it wouldn't generally be good practice).

Comment: Thank you very much @T.J. Crowder +1. I think inherited methods nor accessors (`get`/`set`) will give rise to problems, unless you don't understand the `this` context, or if you do things like `this.__proto__` inside such methods, i.e. **accessing the prototype explicitly of `this`**, that's the only thing I can think of, right?

Comment: @Daniel - The biggest danger I see is if the prototype has a reference to an object and it modifies that object: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/nyhLza81/ That's not directly a change in the prototype, of course (it's a change to a different object the prototype references), but it's a point of confusion for people.

Comment: thank you very much for letting me know those specific cases, I was just going to ask for an example of what you were talking about +1 Now I understand